# Sed matching to the end of the line

Tags: bash, sed

I have a mysqldump with several lines like

```
CONSTRAINT `FK5E61277CBAE1E8F6` FOREIGN KEY (`action_item_group_id`) REFERENCES `action_item_group` (`id`),
```

or

```
CONSTRAINT `FK5E61277CBAE1E8F6` FOREIGN KEY (`action_item_group_id`) REFERENCES `action_item_group` (`id`)
```

I want to add the words `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to each of these, before the comma, if it exists.

In Vi I match it with:
`/CONSTRAINT\ .*\ FOREIGN\ KEY\ .*\ REFERENCES\ .*\ \(.*\)`
which gives me the exact text up to the comma if it exists, or up to the end of the line if it doesn't exist.

But now with `sed` I do:

```
sed -e "s/CONSTRAINT\ .*\ FOREIGN\ KEY\ .*\ REFERENCES\ .*\ \(.*\)/&\ ON\ UPDATE\ CASCADE/"
```

The problem is `&` also matches the comma, and I get output like

```
CONSTRAINT `FK5E61277C881C85E3` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_employee_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`id`), ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

How can I get my `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in before the comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"extended" regular expressions (`-r` flag with `sed`) always make more sense to me. Then you get `\(` meaning a literal parenthesis and `(` meaning start of a group, which is what you seem to be expecting (as per Diego Sevilla). This works for me:

```
echo 'CONSTRAINT `FK5E61277CBAE1E8F6` FOREIGN KEY (`action_item_group_id`) REFERENCES `action_item_group` (`id`),' | sed -r "s/CONSTRAINT\ .*\ FOREIGN\ KEY\ .*\ REFERENCES\ .*\ \(.*\)/&\ ON\ UPDATE\ CASCADE/"
```

result:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK5E61277CBAE1E8F6` FOREIGN KEY (`action_item_group_id`) REFERENCES `action_item_group` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `\` before the parentheses in the substitute expression:

```
sed -e "s/CONSTRAINT\ .*\ FOREIGN\ KEY\ .*\ REFERENCES\ .*\ (.*)/&\ ON\ UPDATE\ CASCADE/"
```

The `\(` means a start of a group, not a parenthesis. `(` just matches the left paren.

Answer (score 2):

Easy with `AWK`:

*EXAMPLE*

```
cat filename.sql | awk '{ cnstr = match($0, "CONSTRAINT"); if (cnstr != 0) { idx = match($0,"\,[^\,]*$"); if (idx == 0) { print $0 " ON UPDATE CASCADE" } else { print substr($0,0,idx-1) " ON UPDATE CASCADE," } } else { print $0 } }' > output.sql
```

***NB***

The `CONSTRAINT` in match can be replaced with whatever regex you want to match. This is just an easy example. It should work though.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just replace the `,` with `ON UPDATE CASCADE,` or did I misunderstand the question?

```
$ echo "some string ending with ," | sed 's/,/NEW,/'
some string ending with NEW,
```

Comment: That doesn't work for lines that don't have the comma. These also have to be added the `ON UPDATE CASCADE`